# yii2 codeception installation error from composer

Tags: yii2, composer-php, codeception

In yii2, i am installing a new module through composer by following command 
 'global require "codeception/codeception = 2.0.*"'[image]
 but it is showing following error

Comment: Please follow the link https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4307  it will definitely help you.

Comment: followed but could not help me out.

Comment: which composer version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
composer self-update

composer global require "codeception/codeception=2.2.10" "codeception/specify=*" "codeception/verify=*"
```